# Emoji not displaying correctly when using vim or tmux

Tags: terminal, fonts, emoji

I am running [Tilix](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/) on Arch Linux. I am having problems with emoji display when running vim or tmux, even though things work correctly in the same terminal when not running vim or tmux.

For demonstration purposes, I have a shell script called `smile` that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo ''
```

When run on the terminal, it produces:

[image]

But when running `tmux` on the same terminal, I get:

[image]

And if I open the script in `vim` I see:

[image]

On my Fedora 31 system, also running Tilix (under Gnome), all of the above works just fine: the emoji displays correctly under tmux and in vim.

Any thoughts on what could be going on here?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Arch Linux?

Comment: @harrymc Yes; pacman reports no available updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need proper Unicode all the way up the stack from OS-Locale, to Terminal, to Tmux, to Vim. Each part of the chain must support Unicode properly.

**For your OS-Locale**

you need something like:
`set LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`

**For Tmux**

Try starting tmux using `tmux -u`, like Jon suggested. If that doesn't work then you might need to check your config files `.tmux.conf` or reset to default.

**FOR VIM**

You need to compile vim with multi-byte support.

The easiest way to do this is to run

```
./configure --with-features=big
make
```

This will build vim with the correct support.

You can verify that it was compiled correctly with

```
:version
```

in vim or by running

```
vim --version
```

and looking for `+multi_byte`.  If it says `-multi_byte` it will not work.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good list of things to check. I'll give that a shot later today.

Comment: I had the same problem; passing `-u` to `tmux` on the command line fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting tmux with the -u flag to enable unicode encoding